# How to implement back button in wicket 1.5

Tags: wicket

I found a lot of example how to create back button in wicket but it was in wicket 1.4 and lower where they use `getPageMap` . This feature isnt in wicket 1.5. I know there are some js feature as `window.history.back()` or `history.go(-1`) but I want implement some clear solution. Any idea ?

My idea was to store webPage in my own webSesion as Stack. Is this good ?

```
public class TournamentSession extends WebSession {

protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Stack<BasePage> previosPage = new Stack<BasePage>();

public TournamentSession(Request request) {
    super(request);
}

public void addPreviosPage(BasePage basePage) {
    logger.info(basePage.getClass().toString());
    previosPage.push(basePage);
}

public BasePage getPreviousPage() {
    BasePage basePage = previosPage.pop();
    logger.info(basePage.getClass().toString());

    return basePage;
}
}
```

and when page are render store actual page to this stack

Comment: Browser navigation is not working as it should for you ? If it works as expected, a JavaScript call is fine in my opinion.

Comment: WebSession has limitation set on size, saving to many pages will lead to session invalidation. http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/Session.html#getSizeInBytes%28%29

Comment: You can also send the previous page as a constructor parameter and use the setResponsePage(previousPage) method

Answer (score 0):

Use `session.getPageManager().getPage(id)`